# ios performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: in viewDidLoad freeze view pushed

Tags: ios, delay, viewdidload, performselector

I push my view controller into navigation

In viewDidLoad method, I place this method in the end line:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startLoadAndParseXML) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.];
```

As usual in my other view controllers in my app, the view controller is pushed then the method startLoadAndParseXML run, and the app is not freezed. But at only one view controller, I don't know why some time the app is freeze, and the view is pushed only after the method startLoadAndParseXML done.

Can anyone explain me? Thank you

Comment: Rather perform that poor selector in backround, right? I'm surprised this worked.

Comment: Yes, it perform on current thread

Answer (score 0):

`performSelectorWithObject:afterDelay:` launches the selector on the current run loop, not in a backgroud thread, so if you call it from the main thread, the networking operations will freeze the UI,

Comment: Hi, the same network actions on other classes don't freeze the app. My app has the same startLoadAndParseXML actions on many view controllers, and the freeze occur only in one class. I think it's my fault, but I can't find.